# Is there a way to self uninstall app on iOS using private API?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

Usual disclaimer: It's not suppose to go to AppStore. It's an experiment.

I am looking for some API which will allow to uninstall app itself. If it will allow to uninstall 3rd party apps, it would be even better.

Comment: There is no such private API. Just like on MAC OS X you need access to   location where apps are installed (`/private/var/mobile/Applications`). You can access this on Jailbroken device. Use NSFileManager to access and delete/uninstall apps.

Comment: @0x8badf00d: "There is no such private API." is very brave judgement. There are tons of different private API. Easily, there could be one in some rarely used private framework which has it

Comment: @0x8badf00d, SpringBoard obviously uninstalls apps.  It would be logical to conclude that *somewhere*, it uses a method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like it should work because it uses `NSFileManager` to perform a simple delete of the whole apps directory

```
NSError *err;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] error:&err];
if (err) {
    NSLog(@"%@", err);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"success");
}
```

Comment: Yeah... Nice try, but it doesn't work. It returns an error "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted""